# visual studio 2015 - копия файлов исходного кода

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

Хотелось бы работать с проектом в одной папке (например, по умолчанию в "Документах"), а в другой папке иметь актуальную копию файлов исходного кода, без генерируемых студией файлов (например, *.sdf).
Подозреваю, что Git способен это сделать, но не разобрался с настройками.

Может кто подсказать что-нибудь по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

Гит именно для этого и нужен.

В гите у вас не только всегда копия вашего проекта, но и вся история изменений, что очень полезно при длительной разработке.

Разбирайтесь, лучше - сразу заливайте на GitHub к примеру.